How to authenticate REST API blob storage operations to use azurite
I am launching azurite from the command line as outlined in the docs and that is working fine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio%2Cblob-storage#running-azurite-from-the-command-line
I am trying to preform GET and PUT blob storage operation from postman but I am unable to figure out how to authorize my requests.
I DO NOT want to use SAS. How do I populate the "Authorization" header with a valid value?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#specifying-the-authorization-header
Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] <AccountName>:<Signature>"  

where SharedKey or SharedKeyLite is the name of the authorization scheme, AccountName is the name of the account requesting the resource, and Signature is a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) constructed from the request and computed by using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded by using Base64 encoding.

for azurite the storage account and key is well documents but how to I use it to create this header

Please read the documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key.

yes I had seen this:

where SharedKey or SharedKeyLite is the name of the authorization scheme, AccountName is the name of the account requesting the resource, and Signature is a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) constructed from the request and computed by using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded by using Base64 encoding.```

for azurite the storage account and key is well documents but how to I use it to create this header

Please read the entire documentation. It has all the necessary steps about how you can create the authorization header.

@entropy283 Check the below answer

@Venkatesan thank you very much for the answer seeing it like this is very helpful. small question, the key that you used, is it the same as the account key listed here?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio%2Cblob-storage#well-known-storage-account-and-key

Yes same but I copied from storage explorer.

@entropy283 Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?

thank you for your comments. I was just trying to have this work for a PUT operation before marking this as resolved :)
simply changing the http method in the string_to_sign did not do it

@entropy283 refr this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id for Put method add necessary headers for PUT Request.

Is the below code worked for get request?

the below code works for get but anything will. you do not even need anything for a GET request (modify the shared key to anything random and you will still be able to access the blob) so it does not prove that this works for everything

another example outlining this is that there is a bug in the answer. in the CanonicalizedResource portion of your string to sign you have specified the account twice in that path but it still managed to work? that seems wrong. try it with put and let me know if it works I don't think it will


How to authenticate REST API blob storage operations to use azurite

I followed this MS-Document,
I started my azurite with below command:
PS C:\Users\azurite> azurite start
Azurite Blob service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10000
Azurite Blob service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10000
Azurite Queue service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10001
Azurite Queue service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10001
Azurite Table service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10002
Azurite Table service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10002


Now, you can use the below code to create sharedkey with date and api version using Python code.
Code:
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    authorization, date, api_version = blobs()

    print(f"Authorization: {authorization}")
    print(f"Date: {date}")
    print(f"API Version: {api_version}")
    input("Press any key to exit...")


def blobs():
    account = "devstoreaccount1"
    key = "xxxx"  # Replace with your access key
    container = "xxx" # Replace with your container name
    blob = "xxx" # Replace with your blob name
    api_version = "2021-06-08"

    dt = datetime.utcnow()
    date_str = dt.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

    string_to_sign = (f"GET\n"  # HTTP method
                     f"\n"  # Content-Encoding
                     f"\n"  # Content-Language
                     f"\n"  # Content-Length
                     f"\n"  # Content-MD5
                     f"\n"  # Content-Type
                     f"\n"  # Date
                     f"\n"  # If-Modified-Since
                     f"\n"  # If-Match
                     f"\n"  # If-None-Match
                     f"\n"  # If-Unmodified-Since
                     f"\n"  # Range
                     f"x-ms-date:{date_str}\n"
                     f"x-ms-version:{api_version}\n"
                     f"/{account}/{account}/{container}/{blob}")

    signature = sign_this(string_to_sign, key)

    # Updated Authorization format
    authorization = f"SharedKey {account}:{signature}"

    return authorization, date_str, api_version


def sign_this(string_to_sign, key):
    decoded_key = base64.b64decode(key)
    string_to_sign = string_to_sign.encode('utf-8')

    hmac_sha256 = hmac.new(decoded_key, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac_sha256.digest()).decode('utf-8')

    return signature


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
Authorization: SharedKey devstoreaccount1:vJp+QagiA/xxxxxxx/Dq49IDmoW76E=
Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2024 05:00:32 GMT
API Version: 2021-06-08


Now, for testing I'm using GET request to get the blob content.
Request:
http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/<container name>/<blob name>
Headers: 
x-ms-version : 2021-06-08
x-ms-date: Fri, 25 Oct 2024 05:00:32 GMT
Authorization:SharedKey devstoreaccount1:vJp+QagiA/xxxxxxx/Dq49IDmoW76E=

Output:

